# Retiring or landing concourse workers

Tags: concourse

We have multiple workers on our concourse cluster. On average each worker has 130 containers. When retiring or landing a worker it will take up to 45 min. We suspect it waits until it removes all volumes from baggage claim.

We are not sure why it takes all that time. My understanding is that it will stop scheduling and wait till jobs are finished then land/retire. it seems it is doing much more.

We are using concourse 3.3.4 with binary deployment.

Answer (score 1):

After upgrading to 3.4.0 the problem seems resolved.